# Reading images from XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read images from my XML file but when I run the code the name from the XML file is not getting passed through to my  tag.

When I inspect the element to see what is rendering I'm getting

```
<img src=".jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
```

Everything seems OK I just don't understand why `r.Value` is not getting passed through.

```
XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader("books.xml");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (r.Read())
{
    switch (r.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            if (r.Name == "Books")
            {
                sb.Append("<table cellpadding=5 cellspacing=2 border=1 >");
                sb.Append("    <tr> <th style=\"text-align:center;\">Title</th> <th style=\"text-align:center;\">ISBN</th> <th style=\"text-align:center;\">Author</th>  ");
                sb.Append("<th style=\"text-align:center;\">Year</th><th style=\"text-align:center;\">Publisher</th> <th style=\"text-align:center;\">Cover</th> </tr>");
            }
            else if (r.Name == "Book")
            {
                sb.Append("    <tr> ");
            }
            else if (r.Name == "Title" ||
                     r.Name == "ISBN" || r.Name == "Author" || r.Name == "Year"
                     || r.Name == "Publisher" || r.Name == "Cover")
            {
                sb.Append("<td>");

                if(r.Name == "Cover")
                {
                    sb.Append("<img src=\"" + r.Value + ".jpg\" height=\"100px\" width=\"100px\" />");
                }
            }  
            break;

        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            if (r.Name == "Cover")
                sb.Append("");
            else
                sb.Append(r.Value);
            break;
    }
}
```

My XML file:

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Title>Angels and Demons</Title>
        <ISBN>9780735643383</ISBN>
        <Author>Dan Brown</Author>
        <Year>2000</Year>
        <Publisher>Pocket Books</Publisher>
        <Cover>images</Cover>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

Comment: Why are you using `XmlReader` instead of one of the higher-level abstractions like LINQ to XML or at worst `XmlDocument`?

Comment: its a project and these are the guidelines. I found so many nice examples to do the same thing but i'm stack with this method.

Comment: Ok, you mean a school project, right?

Comment: Yes. I did everything else but I'm having issues with the image

Comment: Is this XML or HTML? It looks an awful lot like HTML if the latter. I know you said you're limited to using the `XmlReader` but for future reference (once you can start thinking for yourself) the [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is **much** better for parsing HTML.

Comment: Remove the code that isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem, and show us the XML you're trying to process (just the relevant bit, though!)

Comment: well the guidelines require me to render an HTML table depending on what is coming through from the XML file. My issue is right here    **sb.Append("<img src=\"" + r.Value + ".jpg\" height=\"100px\" width=\"100px\" />");** the r.Value does not go through

Comment: @matthewk I added my XML code and I left only the code that I need help with

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, pick one of these short video to get you started: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:youtube.com+debugging+in+c%23

Comment: Now you've removed too much code. We need to see what *r* is and what tests have been made to get to those lines.

Comment: Another hint: use `XmlReader.Create()` instead of `new XmlTextReader()`. The latter has been deprecated since .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading the InnerText property instead of the Value.

Comment: I have changed the r.Value to r.ReadInnerXML() and worked. Thanks much!